# Intent created every time i call onDestroy() and open the activity from recently used app list

Tags: android, android-intent

I created app with launch mode **singleTask** and have intent filter of mime type **Text/plain**, so from other apps when text is selected and share option is chosen, my app is listed and handles the incoming content in **onCreate** and **onNewIntent** methods as follow

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
  Intent intent = getIntent();
  String action = intent.getAction();
  String type = intent.getType();

  if (intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
    sharedData = FileHandler.handleSendText(intent);
  }
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();

    if (intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        sharedData = FileHandler.handleSendText(intent);
    }

    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        finishAndRemoveTask();
    } else {
        finish();
    }

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

I am having a weird behaviour in the app, when new instance of activity is created incoming text is stored in **sharedData** variable through **onCreate** method and when app **onDestroy** method is called(by pressing back button) and start the activity from recently used apps, the **onCreate** method is called which is normal but **Intent.getAction()** and **Intent.getType()** are also returning valid values and if condition is executing! Why is that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, unfortunately, by design :-(

When you select an application from the "recent tasks" list, it launches that application with the same `Intent` that was used to originally launch the application. In your case, the `Intent` with the SEND ACTION.

To fix this, you need to check if the app was launched from the "recent tasks" list, and then act accordingly (ie: ignore the ACTION). Like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if ((intent.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) != 0) {
        // The activity was launched from history
    } else {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();
        if (intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
            sharedData = FileHandler.handleSendText(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After i get intent and with in the app when i change the orientation of screen from portrait to landscape and vice versa,**onCreate** method get called, so in that case **Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY** returns 0 or 1 ?

Comment: The `Intent` that you get in `onCreate()` after an orientation change is exactly the same as the `Intent` that you got in `onCreate()` before the orientation change.

Comment: And also now i am programmatically excluding activity from recents in **onDestroy** method and including again to recents in **onCreate** method, so  will this have any effect on intent flag? Thanks.

Comment: How are you doing that?

Comment: Using `ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.AppTask> tasks; tasks = activityManager.getAppTasks(); tasks.get(0).setExcludeFromRecents(boolean value);`

Comment: I have no clue if that actually works. In any case, it will have no effect `FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY`.

Comment: Checking `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY` is not working in my case. Is there a way to set Intent to null after i am done with Intent ?

Comment: No, there is no way to set the `Intent`. Why isn't the flag working for you?

Comment: Why are you using `singleTask` launch mode? If you let your app be launched into the task of the calling app you wouldn't have this problem. Either that, or you need to declare a separate `Activity` that handles sharing, that runs in a separate task that is excluded from recents, and your main `Activity` runs in a different task.

Comment: As you said i created separate activity that handles sharing and get excluded from recents, now flag is working for the scenario i asked in the question, but it is not working when orientation of screen  is changed before calling `onDestroy()` method.

Comment: Hello, i avoided the activity restart by handling configuration changes by adding these line to manifest `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`. Now problem solved and i am able to  handle configChanges  by overriding `onConfigurationChanged()` . Thanks

Comment: Glad you were able to solve your problem and hopefully you learned a bit more about Android in the process. Happy to help.